# Best way to crop these planks into individual layers, and export them all as separate JPEG files with no white around the edges?

Tags: export, transparency, selections, crop, jpeg

I'm looking for a good workflow in dealing with a document like this. The files need to be JPEG, but I also can't have any white around the planks. Is there a smart way to select and separate each plank into its own layer, and then export them all at once?

[image]

Comment: Select cut paste is the easy bit. Export all at once… I'm assuming you want each cropped to one plank rather than each in its existing place? I don't know how to do that other than manually with Undo between each layer. Life would be a lot easier if all the planks were the same size, then you could paste all at centre & crop once… https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcfB9.png If you only have to do this once, then the manual steps would be OK, 100 different, might get dull...

Comment: [Split to layers script](https://photoshopscripts.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/split-to-layers/). It carries the original layer name over to each resulting layer. — I would then likely use (any) [script for batch renaming layers](https://github.com/joonaspaakko/Photoshop-Rename-Layers-Script) to at the very least add file extension `.jpg` to each layer and then just [`File > Generate > Image assets`](https://github.com/adobe-photoshop/generator-assets/wiki/Generate-Image-Assets-Functional-Spec#getting-started).

Answer (score 1):

First, to select without white line, the best way here is to select with a rectangle with precision by hand (zoom in). Once a plank is selected, `right clic` on it with a select tool active and `Layer via cut`.

Do it for each plank (you can move your selection instead of doing a new one since you seems to have multiple same size here.

Once you have each plank on a layer go to `file > export > Layer to file`. Here you can select the destination folder, and JPEG with the desired quality.

Comment: I actually would select the single planks with the Magic Wand Tool. As there is no background you could set the tolerance to a high value and everything will be selected in your case. Set the contiguous checkbox to checked, so only one plank (and not all) will be selected.